# How to rename files in a for loop in Perl

Tags: perl, loops, for-loop, rename, file-rename

I am running a Perl script and try to accomplish renaming files as below..

I have a list of *.ru.jp files in a folder with other non related files. I would like to rename with a number which I have got as a counter variable.

In Bash,I would do as ...

```
for i in $(ls *.ru.jp); do x=${i%%.*}; mv $i  "$x"t"$counter".ru.jp ;done
```

E.g myfile.ru.jp would be renamed as myfilet1.ru.jp if the counter is 1. "t" is just a naming to indicate t1,t2...etc. And there is an outer loop above all which eventually will label mafilet2.ru.jp and so on as the counter variable increases.

I would like to know how could I write and represent similar for loop as in Perl script?

Thanks.

-joey

Answer (score 8):

```
perl -e 'for $old (@ARGV) {
           ++$counter;
           if (($new=$old) =~ s/(\.ru\.jp)\z/t$counter$1/) {
             rename $old => $new or warn "$0: rename: $!\n";
           }
         }' *.ru.jp
```

Comment: Of course, what happens when you write `push $element => @list`.  Oops, wrong.  Be careful with the fat comma.

Answer (score 7):

You could use Perl's file glob and built-in [rename](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/rename.html) function as follows:

```
use warnings;
use strict;

my $i = 1;
for (<*.ru.jp>) {
    my $file = $_;
    s/\.ru\.jp$//;
    my $new = $_ . 't'. $i . '.ru.jp';
    rename $file, $new or die "Can not rename $file as $new: $!";
    $i++;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I tried this and it seems to do the job:

```
#! /usr/bin/perl

my $count = 0;
for (<*.ru.jp>)
{
        $count++;
        /(.+)\.ru\.jp/;
        rename $_, $1 . "t" . $count . ".ru.jp";
}
```

Comment: Never use capture variables (`$1`, `$2`, and so on) unconditionally! Instead of a semicolon, use `&&` after the match. Yes, I realize it seems like nitpicking in this particular context, but developing this habit will save you from chasing tough bugs.

Comment: Thanks for the advice :) So, you'd rather see something like this?:

/(.+)\.ru\.jp/ && rename $_, $1 . "t" . $count . ".ru.jp";

Comment: Yes, or maybe emphasize the rename by putting it out front: `rename ... if /(.+)\.ru\.jp/`. Both ignore the value returned from `rename`, so any failures will be dangerously silent. You could write `/.../ && (rename ... || warn ...);`, but that seems a little cutesy. Another important habit to develop is to always check the return values of system calls, e.g., `rename`, `open`, `unlink`, etc. Even `print` and `close` can fail, so check them when writing important bits.

Answer (score 1):

```
$count = 1;
for (<*.ru.jp>)
{
        ($filename)=(/^(.*?)\.ru.jp$/);
        rename $_,$filename."t".$count++.".ru.jp";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
use strict;
my $c=0;
rename("$1.ru.jp", "$1" . $c++ . ".ru.jp") while <*.ru.jp> =~ /(.+).ru.jp/;
```

Comment: Good to use strict; would also use warnings.

Answer (score 1):

```
my $counter=0;
while(my $file=<*.ru.jp>){
    $counter++;
    my ($front,$back) = split /\./,$file,2;
    $newname="$front$counter".".t."."$back\n";
    rename $file $newname;
}
```